# Closed queueing networks

Tags: queueing-theory

When applying Norton's theorem to a closed queueing network, most documentation I found assumes same service rates for all queues. How do you calculate the throughput and delay if the service times are different for each queue? Does rate conservation apply?

Answer (score 0):

This paper details how to apply Norton's theorem to a queueing network where (on the second page) "the service rate for the $i$th queue when there are $k$ custoers is $U_i(k)$, where $i=1,\ldots,M$ and $k=1,\ldots,N$." This therefore isn't assuming the same service rate for each queue.

- Chandy, K. M.; Herzog, U.; Woo, L. (Jan 1975). *[Parametric Analysis of Queuing Networks](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.93.9312&rep=rep1&type=pdf)*. IBM Journal of Research and Development 19 (1): 36–42. doi:[10.1147/rd.191.0036](http://dx.doi.org/10.1147/rd.191.0036).

I'm not sure what you mean by rate conservation.